# Is it possible to evaluate a fraction of exponetial to sum of exponentials

Tags: r, nan, fractions, exponential

I want to evaulate a fraction like this:

[image]

or

```
\begin{equation}  
\frac{e^{y_t}}{\sum_{i=1}^T{e^{y_i}}}  
\end{equation}
```

for large y values. But a statistical software (e.g., R) can not evaluate exp(800) or even larger numbers. Then the problem is that the fraction is evaluated to NaN. But we know that this fraction is always between 0 and 1. Is it possible to use some mathematical or programming tricks to fix the problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: I've not used it, but this R library: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html allows for numbers with arbitrary precision (i.e. they can get as big as you have memory and computing power for)

Comment: I will try this, thanks a lot for recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try

- put 1 on top, and distribute the `exp(-Y[t])` into each term of the sum
- simplify each term of the sum, by summing the exponents

or some such algebra.

Another way to look at it ...

You say the overall fraction is between 0 and 1.
Well, if it's close to 1, that means the denominator is bound to be reasonable.

If it's close to 0, that means the denominator is very large.
So if you're summing the denominator, and it gets unreasonably large, just quit.
You know it can only increase.

Also, you could sort the terms of the sum, doing the ones with the largest exponent first.
That way you get to the unreasonableness sooner.

Comment: Maybe I did not make it clear. The problem here is that, say when y_t = 800, exp(800) is evaluated to be Inf. Then the denominator is also Inf. And Inf/Inf is not defined. But if the software (or the computer) is powerful enough, it will evaluate exp(800) as a large but finite number. And so will the denominator. Then the whole fraction is a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: @user2966729: I was trying to suggest you scale the entire thing by `exp(-Y_t)`, hoping that would bring the terms in the summation down to reasonable numbers. It shouldn't be necessary to divide enormous numbers by enormous numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I regreted at the moment I added my first comment. Your idea is great. I failed to realize this simple way.

Comment: @user2966729: Good luck. Math is fun :)